# Password generation function with at least 1 number, 1 uppercase letter and 1 lowercase letter

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have my function generating a random password made with letters and numbers.

I'd like to have at least 1 number, 1 uppercase letter and 1 lowercase letter. Do you have any idea ?

Here is my code :

```js
// Range of letters and numbers to include in the password
// Modify if needed to add or remove characters
var PASSWORD_CHARS_RANGE = "abcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789";

/**
* Return a randomly generated password of the given length. If no length is provided, defaults to 8.
*
* @param {number} length (Optional) The length of the password - Default is 8 characters
* @return A password
* @customfunction
*/

function PASSWORD(length){
  
  var passwordLength = 8;
  var password = "";
  
  // Do some checks on the params
  if ((typeof length !== "undefined") && ((length >= 1) && (typeof length === "number") && Math.floor(length) === length)){
    passwordLength = length;
  }
  
  // Add random characters to the password string
  for (var i = 0; i < passwordLength; i ++){
   password += PASSWORD_CHARS_RANGE.charAt(Math.random() * PASSWORD_CHARS_RANGE.length);
  }
  
  return password;
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: What steps have you taken to try to implement something?

Comment: Keep only lowercase letters and numbers in PASSWORD_CHARS_RANGE string. Use an array and push random characters in the array for the length or convert generated string to char array. Check for 1 number in the array to satisfy your condition. Update random characters to upper string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the uppercase characters and numbers from `PASSWORD_CHARS_RANGE`, then add this code segment to convert lowercase characters to uppercase and numbers:

```
  // change random number of characters (1 to length-2) to uppercase
    var uc = Math.ceil(Math.random()*(passwordLength-2));
    for (var j = 0; j < uc; j++) {
      var idx1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*(passwordLength-1));
      password = password.substr(0,idx1)+password.charAt(idx1).toUpperCase()+password.substr(idx1+1); 
    }
    
  // change random number of characters (1 to length-uc-1) to numbers
    var un = Math.ceil(Math.random()*(passwordLength-uc-1));
    for (var k = 0; k < un; k++) {
      var idx2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*(passwordLength-1));
      if (password.charAt(idx2) === password.charAt(idx2).toLowerCase()) {
         password = password.substr(0,idx2)+String(Math.floor(Math.random()*10))+password.substr(idx2+1);
      }
      else --k;
    }
```

Running the function on a sample sheet gives:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Manohar407278512

```js
// Range of letters and numbers to include in the password
// Modify if needed to add or remove characters
var PASSWORD_CHARS_RANGE = "abcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789";

/**
* Return a randomly generated password of the given length. If no length is provided, defaults to 8.
*
* @param {number} length (Optional) The length of the password - Default is 8 characters
* @return A password
* @customfunction
*/

function PASSWORD(length){
  
  var passwordLength = 8;
  var password = "";
  
  // Do some checks on the params
  if ((typeof length !== "undefined") && ((length >= 1) && (typeof length === "number") && Math.floor(length) === length)){
    passwordLength = length;
  }
  
  // Add random characters to the password string
  for (var i = 0; i < passwordLength; i ++){
   password += PASSWORD_CHARS_RANGE.charAt(Math.random() * PASSWORD_CHARS_RANGE.length);
  }
  
  return password;
}
```

```js
// Range of letters and numbers to include in the password
// Modify if needed to add or remove characters
var PASSWORD_CHARS_RANGE = "abcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789";

/**
* Return a randomly generated password of the given length. If no length is provided, defaults to 8.
*
* @param {number} length (Optional) The length of the password - Default is 8 characters
* @return A password
* @customfunction
*/

function PASSWORD(length){
  
  var passwordLength = 8;
  var password = "";
  
  // Do some checks on the params
  if ((typeof length !== "undefined") && ((length >= 1) && (typeof length === "number") && Math.floor(length) === length)){
    passwordLength = length;
  }
  
  // Add random characters to the password string
  for (var i = 0; i < passwordLength; i ++){
   password += PASSWORD_CHARS_RANGE.charAt(Math.random() * PASSWORD_CHARS_RANGE.length);
  }
  
  return password;
}
```